# Clojure, Agent, lack side-effects

Tags: clojure, agent

I'm using agents to manipulate a structure, but I don't have all my side effects.

All the messages are sent(I've printed and counted them), but there are times when I don't have all my side-effects. As if not all of my functions were applied on the agent's state, or if the last send is applied on a previous state..

I experimented with doall, dorun but haven't find a solution, appreciate any help.

```
;; aux function for adding an element to a hashmap 
(defn extend-regs [reg s o]
  (let [os (get reg s)]
    (if (nil? os)
      (assoc reg s [o])
      (assoc reg s (conj os o)))))

;; the agent's altering function - adding an element to the :regs field(a hashmap)
(defn add-reg! [d s o]
  (send d (fn [a] (assoc a :regs (extend-regs (:regs a) s o)))))



;; Creating the agents, dct/init returns an agent
;; pds: data for fields
(defn pdcts->init-dcts! [pds]
  (doall (map dct/init (map :nam pds) (repeat nil))))

;; Altering one agent's state,  dct/add-reg  sends an assoc message to the agent
;; d: agent,  pd: data for fields
(defn dct->add-regs! [d pd]
  (dorun (map (fn [s r] (dct/add-reg! d s r))
          (:syms pd)
          (:regs pd)))
  d)

;; Going through all agents
;; ds: agents,  pds: datas
(defn dcts->add-regs! [ds pds]
  (dorun (map (fn [d pd] (dct->add-regs! d pd))
          ds
          pds))
  ds)
```

EDIT: =====================================================

Okay it turned out I just haven't wait enough to my threads to finish their tasks. Now the question is how can I monitor my agents. How can I know that there are unfinished threads in the queue?  I've only found swank.core/*active-threads* and similar ones but they are not a solution.

Comment: I haven't tested your code, but you might be getting an exception when your function is executed by the agent. Afterwards, the agent won't accept any new commands and will keep its state. You need to call clojure.core/agent-error on the agent to return the exception and then clojure.repl/pst on the exception to get the stacktrace.

Comment: Thx for the reply! I tried agent-error on the failed cases, but I got nils, so no exceptions. Anyway thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [await](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/await) or [await-for](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/await-for) to wait until an agent finished it's current work queue:

```
(await agent1 agent2 agent3)
```

or

```
(apply await list-of-agents)
```

A minor improvement of add-reg:

```
(defn extend-regs [reg s o]
  (update-in reg [s] conj o))
```

This works because of

```
(conj nil :b)               ; => [:b]
```

thus

```
(update-in {} [:a] conj :b) ; => {:a [:b]}
```

finally we have.

```
(defn add-reg! [d s o]
  (send d update-in s [:regs] conj o)
```

Answer (score 2):

I do not have a solution for your problem, but I can't resist suggesting some improvement on the first two functions:

```
(defn extend-regs [reg s o]
  (let [os (get reg s)]
    (if (nil? os)
      (assoc reg s [o])
      (assoc reg s (conj os o)))))
;; => place the 'if inside the assoc:
(defn extend-regs [reg s o]
  (let [os (get reg s)]
    (assoc reg s (if (nil? os) [o] (conj os o)))))
;; => this (if (nil? x) ...) is the pattern of function fnil, so ...
(defn extend-regs [reg s o]
  (let [os (get reg s)]
    (assoc reg s ((fnil conj []) os o))))
;; with update-in, this will be even clearer, and we can remove the let altogether:
(defn extend-regs [reg s o]
  (update-in reg [s] (fnil conj []) o))
```

As for the second:

```
(defn add-reg! [d s o]
  (send d (fn [a] (assoc a :regs (extend-regs (:regs a) s o)))))
;; => We can, again, use update-in instead of assoc:
(defn add-reg! [d s o]
  (send d (fn [a] (update-in a [:regs] extend-regs s o))))
;; or, if you can get rid of extend-regs:
(defn add-reg! [d s o]
  (send d (fn [a] (update-in a [:regs s] (fnil conj []) o)))
```

Finally, as a matter of style, I would place add-reg in a separate function, and directly use the idiom of sending to the agent in the client code (or have a simplified add-reg! function):

```
(defn add-reg [v s o] (update-in v [:regs s] (fnil conj []) o))

(defn add-reg! [d s o] (send d add-reg))
```

I know this doesn't answer your initial question, but it was fun to write this step by step refactoring

Comment: Yes I haven't know about these, thx for pointing them out!! Indeed I've just found out that the my states not altered because not all my threads terminated, I haven't wait enough..